# Vue - rendering templates after Ajax call

Tags: ajax, vue.js, drupal

I have a page which loads some information chunks at the beginning and it loads other ones when user scroll down. In this chunks I have also , for which I have a function written.
Simplified structure of the chunk looks like that:

```
<div class="chunk_class">
  <div class="chunk_header">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="subtitle"></div>
  </div>
   ....
  <div class="actions">
     <comparison-training-toggle training-id="70" init-comparison="0" icon="n-compare" class="v-comparison-toggle" title="Some title"></comparison-training-toggle>
     <div class="another_action"></div>
  </div>
```

It works for the chunks that I load at page load, but it doesn't work for the other ones that I load through Ajax call. How can I make it work also for Ajax loaded ones? Do I need to install some other modules (I have now installed Vue, Vue-resource & Vue-router)?
Below part of the function that I wrote with comments what does and what doesn't work:

```
  $(document, context).once('vue__comparison_toggle_add').each(() => {
    Drupal.behaviors.vue__comparison_toggle.vueComponent(); //this works
  });
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings){
    Drupal.behaviors.vue__comparison_toggle.vueComponent();//it enters the the ajaxComplete, but doesn't work, it still remains <comparison-training-toggle>...
  });
},
vueComponent: function () {
    Vue.component('comparison-training-toggle', {
      template: this.template,
      props: ['trainingId', 'icon', 'init-comparison'],
      data() {
        return {
          inComparison: false,
        }
      },
      computed: {
        toggleText() {
          return this.inComparison ? Drupal.t('Usuń z porównania') : Drupal.t('Dodaj do porównania')
        }
      },
      methods: {
        toggle() {
          ...
```

Comment: I'd say, get away from using jQuery and use regular `async/await` with some isomorphic fetch so that it's closer to web standards.

Comment: ok, but it doesn't solve my problem ;)

Comment: That may help more than you think actually.